# 2-periodic derived equivalence

Tags: rt.representation-theory, derived-categories, triangulated-categories, morita-equivalence, tilting

Let $A$ and $B$ be finite-dimensional algebras with finite global dimension over some field (in fact I am thinking of rational incidence algebras of finite posets).

Suppose we know that $A$ and $B$ are derived equivalent (for instance using [Ladkani's results on universally derived equivalent posets](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0705.0946v2.pdf)). Then by [Zhao: A note on the equivalence of $m$-periodic derived categories](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs11425-014-4852-9) the $2$-periodic derived categories of *finite-dimensional* modules over $A$ respectively $B$ are triangle-equivalent.

Question: Is there a way to conclude that the $2$-periodic derived categories of *countable-dimensional* modules over $A$ respectively $B$ are triangle-equivalent as well?

In the non-periodic setting, a derived equivalence gives a perfect tilting module that should yield equivalences of derived categories of modules of any desired size.

The $2$-periodic derived category of $A$-modules is also the derived category of the dg algebra $A[\beta^{\pm 1}]$ with $A$ in degree $0$ and an invertible "Bott" element $\beta$ of degree $2$, and with trivial odd entries and trivial differentials. But at least for dg rings, a derived equivalence need not be induced by a tilting module (see Theorem 3.11 and Proposition 3.14 in [Keller's ICM address](http://www.icm2006.org/proceedings/Vol_II/contents/ICM_Vol_2_08.pdf)). Since the counterexample involves torsion and non-trivial differentials, one could still hope that things work out in the nice case at hand where we work with rational graded algebras vanishing in odd degrees.

Comment: Isn't it true that the 2-periodic derived category is the fixed point subcategory of the square of the translation functor $T$? Therefore, if $A$ and $B$ have triangle equivalent derived categories, then their  $T^2$-fixed point subcategories shall also be triangle equivalent, right?

Comment: It’s been a while since I’ve thought about this, but this sounds reasonable, thank you!